# No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Microsoft.CSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

tengo el siguiente problema y no encuentro por ningún lado un problema similar, ¿alguien lo ha tenido?.

En la consola me aparece el siguiente error al iniciar la depuración de mi proyecto web.

```
No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ni una de sus dependencias. Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80070542
```

Comment: Agregaste la referencia a `Microsoft.CSharp`?

Comment: Intenta ejecutar visual studio como administrador tambien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como mencionó [nacl](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/4499/nacl), me faltaba agregar la referencia a Microsoft.CSharp. Han pasado los meses y ahora me doy cuenta que era un problema muy tonto, por si alguien que va inciando en C# le pasa algo parecido.